# TLS: Are the following considered 'weak' ciphers?

Tags: tls, ciphers

A customer I'm currently working with has reported the following as 'weak' cipher suites in use on a site:

```
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

The reasoning being: 'The highlighted issues are SHA is no longer supported (use SHA256 or SHA384), 128 bit ciphers are no longer supported.'

Are these observations valid? I'm assuming they can have their own internal policies that make them valid, but do they sound reasonable? The site gets an A on the Qualys test.

Comment: You are actually asking two questions and for both exist answers: for AES128 see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116895/is-aes-128-encryption-weak-for-very-small-payload-size and for SHA1 as HMAC see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90385/obsolete-cryptography-sha1-warning-although-certificate-uses-sha256 or http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure.

Comment: Google uses AES128-GCM.  Does your client also not use Google?  They sound somewhat unreasonable.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the links, but I'm still struggling to see how this is an 'exact duplicate' of an existing question.

Comment: @MarkKelly: In my opinion your question is answered by the ones I've linked to because they handle the strength of AES128 and SHA-1 within ciphers. If you feel that parts are not handled by these answers then please specify the exact issues which are still open.